# How does a current flow in here if this is not a loop?

Tags: current

Below is an image from Microelectronic circuits by Sedra & Smith — Seventh edition.

[image]

How can a current of 10 mA flow in this circuit (in figure a) if there is no loop for the current to flow in? Is there an implicit assumption that the ground and +10V end of this circuit magically form a loop (which is omitted here)? Not even interested in the diode at this point. How would this be physically possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common way to simplify circuit diagrams.  The "+10V" label and little arrow mean that that point on the circuit is connected to something (such as a battery or power supply) which is also connected to ground (the symbol at the bottom).

The three diagrams below mean exactly the same thing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftTNnw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In your case, the textbook has gone a step further and missed out the battery entirely. Probably becasue it doesn't matter for the discussion at hand.

Answer (score 6):

Because some circuit diagrams are to illustrate ideas rather than complete implementations. These focus on the essentials without introducing irrelevant details.

Thus the following two circuits are identical.

In the first one, the labels indicate that a voltage source is connected to supply 10V at the named label, and by convention, its other node is 0V connected to GND. You already know that a voltage source supplies volts, and has zero internal impedance, by the time you see this circuit. (If not, you have missed some pre-requisites for reading this book/taking this course).

In the second, this is explicit, and you can easily see the loop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCz3Iw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Simplifying the circuit makes it easier to focus on the important point in these figures : in this case, the orientation of the diode.

Bear in mind that many circuits you see are illustrations, rather than complete implementations ready for layout to PCB.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that the 10V supply and the ground are in fact coming from a power supply or simply a battery. It's just not drawn as it is irrelevant, as the 10V supply, regardless of what it is, will close the loop.

Comment: So just to clarify we should expect to find a path between the ground and +10V, but it is omitted?

Comment: Yes. If it helps you, you can draw another set of 10V and GND symbols and a 10V voltage source.

Comment: Yes, through the power source not shown explicitly.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot everyone! I know this is a reasonably trivial question, but I've needed a sanity check because my lecturer seems to be abusing/not explaining notation his notation.

Answer (score -5):

A current can be induced by electromagnetic waves without needed to be closed loops.In fact most antennas are open circuits yet they can carry electromagnetic information.

Just because when we are taught about the electric circuits our books say that a closed loop must exist for current to flow but it is not necessary.